# Looking for solution to have specific terms have automatic tooltips whenever entered into content items

Tags: tooltips

I would like to have specific text automatically (or manually) insert a tooltip.

For example, let's say I want every instance on the website of:

```
CMS
```

And have the tooltip say:

```
"Content Management System"
```

For drupal to automatically add this would be nice...but not asking for that much ;)

Can I add some kind of dynamic token?

The html can be static since the CSS is bootstrap CDN:

```
<p>Drupal is the best <strong><span data-placement="top" data-  toggle="tooltip" title="Content Management System" type="button">CMS</span></strong> in the world.</p>
```

Comment: [Drupal Text Formats 102: Developing custom filters](http://pingv.com/blog/drupal-text-formats-102-developing-custom-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom javascript that wraps all strings you want to replace with the `<span data-toogle="tooltip"></span>`

here's a [tutorial](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/)

```
// Pretending we have more than one paragraph to look through
jQuery('p').each(function(){
    traverseChildNodes(this);
});

function traverseChildNodes(node) {

    var next;

    if (node.nodeType === 1) {

        // (Element node)

        if (node = node.firstChild) {
            do {
                // Recursively call traverseChildNodes
                // on each child node
                next = node.nextSibling;
                traverseChildNodes(node);
            } while(node = next);
        }

    } else if (node.nodeType === 3) {

        // (Text node)

        if (/CMS/.test(node.data)) {
            // Do something interesting here
            alert('FOUND A MATCH!');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a custom module:

```
function MODULE_filter_info() {
  $filters = array();
  $filters['inline_terms'] = array(
    'title' => t('Term definitions inline'),
    'process callback' => '_MODULE_inline_terms_filter',

  );
  return $filters;
}

function _MODULE_inline_terms_filter($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id) {
  switch ($filter->name) {
    case 'inline_terms':
      $glossary = **... get your glossary array list from somewhere**

      foreach($glossary as $key => $item) {
        $text = str_replace($key, '<span data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="' . $item . '" type="button">' . $key . '</span>);
      }
      break;    
  }

  return $text;
}
```

If the requirement is **whole word replacements** only, then you can look at [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), as in this post:

[str_replace: Match whole word only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682629/str-replace-match-whole-word-only)

The benefits of using a text filter is that the content is left untouched in the database. Only when the content is rendered with a cache miss is the filter run over the text.